# How to add a Fetched Property (to a DataModel) programmatically?

Tags: ios, core-data

In order to find a way arround, to solve a problem posted here: [Core Data Lightweight Migration not working when a Fetched Property is present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35115410/core-data-lightweight-migration-not-working-when-a-fetched-property-is-present)

I am trying to see if I can add a `Fetched Property` to an entity programmatically (on the DataModel), before doing anything else on the entity.

But what I have tried at this point has failed. Here is the code I use:

```
    NSEntityDescription *myEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"EntityName"
                                                inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSFetchedPropertyDescription *myFetchProp = [[NSFetchedPropertyDescription alloc] init];
    [myFetchProp setName:@"myFetchPropName"];
    [myEntity setProperties:[[myEntity properties] arrayByAddingObject:myFetchProp]];
```

There is a crash happening on the last line, here what I can see in the debugger:

```
(lldb) bt
* thread #1: tid = 0xc2b17, 0x0000000180c3bf48 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
    frame #0: 0x0000000180c3bf48 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw
    frame #1: 0x00000001830e0b70 CoreData`-[NSManagedObjectModel(_NSInternalMethods) _throwIfNotEditable] + 80
    frame #2: 0x00000001830aa0f8 CoreData`-[NSEntityDescription setProperties:] + 52
  * frame #3: 0x000000010007b2b4 parl100`-[XYZLib transferDataFromDefaultStoreToUserStore](self=0x000000015654dba0,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [NSManagedObjectModel class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectModel_Class/index.html):

> Managed object models are editable until they are used by an object graph manager (a managed object context or a persistent store coordinator).

So you need to amend the model *as you build the CoreData stack* rather than when you are using the context.  So, if you get the base model from the bundle, you might use something like this:

```
NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"YourApp" withExtension:@"momd"];
NSManagedObjectModel *mom = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
NSManagedObjectModel *newMOM = [mom copy];
NSEntityDescription *myEntity = [[newMOM entitiesByName] objectForKey:@"EntityName"];
NSFetchedPropertyDescription *fp = [[NSFetchedPropertyDescription alloc] init];
fp.name = @"myFetchedPropertyName";
NSFetchRequest *fpFetch = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
// configure fetched property fetch request
fp.fetchRequest.entity = myOtherEntity;
fp.fetchRequest.predicate = myFPPredicate;
// Add the fetched property to the entity's properties:
NSMutableArray *currentProperties = [NSMutableArray
                                     arrayWithArray:[myEntity properties]];
[currentProperties addObject:fp];
myEntity.properties = currentProperties;
return newMOM;
```

I should say I have not needed to do this "for real", so can't advise on the full ramifications - you might, for example, be setting yourself up for a nightmare if/when you need to roll out a new version of the model.

Comment: I have tested your code and it seems to work. Thanks.
I am not sure though why (whether) you need to set "fp.fetchRequest.entity = myOtherEntity;" at this level. Or I am missing some subtleties?

Comment: @Michel According to the docs, the fetched property description (like the rest of the model) becomes immutable as soon as the model is associated with a PSC.  So the line you refer to is there to specify which entity is fetched - the equivalent of the "destination" in the model editor for fetched properties.

Answer (score 1):

**To create fields**

```
+(NSEntityDescription*)entityDescription
{
NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription new];
entityDescription.name = @"EntityName";

entityDescription.managedObjectClassName = NSStringFromClass(self);

//Describe date attribute creation.
NSAttributeDescription *creationDateDescription =  
[NSAttributeDescription new];
creationDateDescription.name = @"creationDate";
creationDateDescription.attributeType = NSDateAttributeType;
creationDateDescription.attributeValueClassName = @"NSDate";
creationDateDescription.defaultValue = nil;    

//Describe archivedObject.    
NSAttributeDescription *archivedObjectDescription =   
[NSAttributeDescription new];
archivedObjectDescription.name = @"archivedObject";    
archivedObjectDescription.attributeType = NSBinaryDataAttributeType;
archivedObjectDescription.attributeValueClassName = @"NSData";
archivedObjectDescription.defaultValue = nil;

//Add attributes.
entityDescription.properties = @[ creationDateDescription, archivedObjectDescription ];

//Voila.
return entityDescription;
}
```

**for fetch**

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"EntityName"];

NSError *error;
id results = [appdel.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
int i=100;
if ([results count])
{
    for (NSManagedObject *object1 in results)
    {
        NSManagedObjectClass  *object = (NSManagedObjectClass *)object1;
    }
}
```

**For save**

```
        NSManagedObject   *object = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"EntityName" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        NSManagedObjectClass  *polyline = (NSManagedObjectClass *)object;
        polyline.json_string=request.responseString;
       if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error1]) {
            NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
```

Comment: How will this  add a Fetched Property to my entity ?

Comment: Thanks. My problem is to add a Fetched Property (programmatically) to an entity, that Fetched Property does not yet exist in the data-model. I don't see how the code you write does that. Your code creates an object and saves it, but this is not what I need now. To understand my question you may first want to have a look at the link I mention at the beginning of the post.